# Recharts graph doesnt render correct

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am currently working on an component that fetch data from 2 different end points. First end point delivers multiple data measured by sensors and a timestamp. The second endpoint offers predicted values for sensor data and timestamp also. After i fetch the data i combine the fetched data and try to create a chart based on combined data, having diferent lines for every measured or predicted parameters. For chart I,m using Rechart library. When i first load the page with the graphics, the graph displays all the data as i intended, but after a second or two, the chart is losing some of the values and "shrinks".
Another mention is that the requests for data are made for a range of days and im using a datetimepicker for choosing the range. After the graph loads, if i change the range the new set of data is displayed correctly so the problem occurs only on the first render i think.
Does anyone had a problem like this? Or what can be the cause of it?